# ScriptSharp, Unable to Resolve Referenced Type

Tags: script#

I am writing some custom objects for our business that requires I use script#. The documentation recommends these steps:

Create project of type C#>Script#>Class Library - Class Library is not listed as a template so I have tried with both Script Library and JQuery Script Library.

Confirm that the Script.Web.dll is present - It is referenced

Add the following references (these are custom DLL's provided by our software's SDK) - xx.Web.AddIns, xx.Web.Core, xx.Web.ObjectModel, xx.Web.UI.Controls. I added references to these dlls.

In the provided cs class file I implemented a class based off of a premade interface, I chose a simple class to implement.

When building the project I receive error "Unable to resolve referenced type 'System.DateTime'. Make sure all needed assemblies have been explicitly referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a simple class. Use a script# class. This should resolve your issue and build your class with the correct references.